# How can call the button click without clicking the button

Tags: android

I have a button declare with login function as follows.

```
<Button
android:text="@string/btnNext"
android:id="@+id/btnNext"
android:onClick="login"/>
```

login function:

```
public void login(View view){
   xxxxxxxxx
}
```

is it possible to trigger a click without clicking a button?

Comment: call login(view) method from oncreate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to initialise control in `onCreate()` method

```
btnNext = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
```

then you call it from code behind like this

```
btnNext.performClick();
```

Answer (score 3):

call performClick() method

`btn.performClick();`